# how to remove case sensitivty in quick search?`

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SearchData li").hide();

  $('#SearchData li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-text', function() {
      return $(this).text();
    });
  });

  $('#quickSearchInput').bind('change keypress  keyup change', function() {
    $("#SearchData li").hide();
    $('#SearchData li[data-text*="' + $.trim($(this).val()) + '"]').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quickSearchInput" />
<ul id="SearchData">
  <li>ABC</li>
  <li>DCD</li>
  <li>AFG</li>
  <li>XYZ</li>
  <li>abC</li>
  <li>xYz</li>
</ul>
```

when i try to search the Jquery search according to case sensitive.. how can i make it case insenstive to search quickly

Thanks

Comment: here is jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/taqiniazi/m0689edp/1/

Comment: Use `.toLowerCase()` method to set the text as a value of `data-text` attribute in lowercase. [demo](https://jsbin.com/decunibawa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: use a regular expression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.prototype.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to set the attribute value in lower case.

**Please Note:**
As the data is shown on page load then goes hiden after page load, I will suggest you to hide them using CSS.

Also you should not use `bind()`, you can simply use `on()` with `input`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#SearchData li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-text', function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    });
  });

  $('#quickSearchInput').on('input', function() {
    $("#SearchData li").hide();
    $('#SearchData li[data-text*="' + $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase()) + '"]').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#SearchData li{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quickSearchInput" />
<ul id="SearchData">
  <li>ABC</li>
  <li>DCD</li>
  <li>AFG</li>
  <li>XYZ</li>
  <li>abC</li>
  <li>xYz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both `options` and `searchString` to same case. You can use `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#SearchData li").hide();

  $('#SearchData li').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('data-text', function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    });
  });

  $('#quickSearchInput').bind('change keypress  keyup change', function() {
    $("#SearchData li").hide();
    $('#SearchData li[data-text*="' + $.trim($(this).val().toLowerCase()) + '"]').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quickSearchInput" />
<ul id="SearchData">
  <li>ABC</li>
  <li>DCD</li>
  <li>AFG</li>
  <li>XYZ</li>
  <li>abC</li>
  <li>xYz</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast data-text strings to lower case using `$(this).text().toLowerCase()` and cast your jquery search parameter to lower case also: `...val().toLowerCase()`.

Didn’t test to make sure syntax is correct but concept should work.

Answer (score 0):

in  JS:

```js
const quickSearchInput = document.querySelector('#quick-Search-Input')
  ,   SearchDataElms   = document.querySelectorAll ('#Search-Data li')
  ;
quickSearchInput.oninput = e =>
  {
  let regTest = new RegExp( quickSearchInput.value, 'i')  // insensitive  case 

  SearchDataElms.forEach(el=>
    {
    el.style.display = regTest.test(el.textContent) ? 'list-item' : 'none'
    })
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="quick-Search-Input" />
<ul id="Search-Data">
    <li>ABC</li>
    <li>DCD</li>
    <li>AFG</li>
    <li>XYZ</li>
    <li>abC</li>
    <li>xYz</li>
</ul>
```